# Layers don't match on OpenLayers

Tags: geoserver, coordinate-system, openlayers, openlayers-2, epsg

In my Openlayers 3.9.0, I use Bing Maps and OSM layers. They both are `EPSG 3857`.

```
var layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM({})
    });

    var bingMapsAerial = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.BingMaps({
            key: '////',
            imagerySet:'AerialWithLabels'
        })
    });
```

I set the extent that the layers mast fit in

```
var textent = ol.proj.transformExtent([2297128.5, 4618333, 2459120.25, 4763120], 'EPSG:900913', 'EPSG:3857');
```

I also set a layer from PostGIS

```
    var ait = new ol.layer.Tile({
    extent: textent,
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/mymap/wms?',      
       params: {'LAYERS': 'mymap:polygon, mymap:line', 'TILED': true,  'VERSION': '1.3.0','FORMAT': 'image/png' ,'CRS': 'EPSG:3857'},
       serverType: 'geoserver'
     })
   })
```

My view is

```
var view = new ol.View({
    center: center,
    extent : textent,
    zoom: 6,
    maxZoom:20
});
```

and my map

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers:[bingMapsAerial, layer, ait],
    view: view
});

map.getView().fit(textent, map.getSize());
```

The raster tile layer is in `EPSG 900913` in PostGIS and Geoserver says `EPSG:900913` as `Native SRS` and `Declared SRS`. Both `polygon` and `line` layers that compose the tile layer have slightly different `Native Bounding Box` and `Lat/Lon Bounding Box`, but they render the same spatial region.
Both `polygon` and `line` layers have `Published zoom levels` and `Cached zoom levels` set to 0 -20 in Geoserver to match the Openlayers View settings

Aren't `EPSG 900913` and `EPSG 3857` supposed to be the same?

Both Bing and OSM layers look ok, but the tile layer appears smaller than the other two.

How do I proceed? Am I missing something, a setting or var? Is there a hack? Do I have to convert the PostGIS data?

Comment: What's the purpose of `ol.proj.transformExtent`?  That return value should be the same as the input.

Comment: @Mintx I am trying to convert the Bounting Box from its original `EPSG 900913` to `EPSG 3857` that the layers have. Sorry I dont actually get you

Comment: As you mentioned in the question, `EPSG 900913` and `EPSG 3857` are identical, so the bounding box values shouldn't change. If they do change, then there's something wrong with `ol.proj.transformExtent`.

Comment: @Mintx If I go [here](http://cs2cs.mygeodata.eu/) and transform from `900913` to `3857` the coords are identical. The new problem is when I try to do `var textent = ol.extent[2297128.5, 4618333, 2459120.25, 4763120];` layers fit, but the map is not zoomed in correctly to the defined area and I get `Uncaught AssertionError: Assertion failed: invalid extent or geometry` from OpenLayers. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

I have found that mis-aligned WMS layers are often due to differences between the cache and client config.

GeoWebCache, the cache server integrated with GeoServer, will silently accept a 10% diff between the closest cached resolution and the requested resolution.

I would disable caching entirely on your local tile server to see if it fixes your issue. If it does, you have confirmed that it is a cache issue and can investigate it further.